# Iterating over a dictionary in python and stripping white space

Tags: python, dictionary, whitespace, strip

I am working with the web scraping framework Scrapy and I am wondering how do I iterate over all of the scraped items which seem to be in a dictionary and strip the white space from each one.

Here is the code I have been playing with in my item pipeline:

```
for info in item:
   info[info].lstrip()
```

But this code does not work, because I cannot select items individually. So I tried to do this:

```
for key, value item.items():
   value[1].lstrip()
```

This second method works to a degree, but the problem is that I have no idea how then to loop over all of the values.

I know this is probably such an easy fix, but I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: I would suggest you have a look at http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html. A lot of cleanup can be take care of here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a direct answer to the question, but I would suggest you look at [Item Loaders](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) and input/output processors. A lot of your cleanup can be take care of here.

An example which strips each entry would be:

```
class ItemLoader(ItemLoader):

    default_output_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
```

Comment: your answer is exactly what I was looking for! thank you so much. even though it's not exactly what I asked.. it is what i needed it worked perfect. so thank you so much!

Answer (score 30):

In a dictionary comprehension (available in Python >=2.7):

```
clean_d = { k:v.strip() for k, v in d.iteritems()}
```

Python 3.X:

```
clean_d = { k:v.strip() for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: Nice. Note that dict comprehension is only available in Python >=2.7.

Comment: Shawn, thanks, I forgot to mention the version restriction.  I've added a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
for k,v in item.items():
   item[k] = v.replace(' ', '')
```

or in a comprehensive way as suggested by monkut:

```
newDic = {k,v.replace(' ','') for k,v in item.items()}
```

Comment: thank you for you help. I do have one question, is there some trick to the .replace() function, because when I try using it python spits out an error saying list element has no atrabute replace(). is there something i need to include?

Comment: @AlexW.H.B.: Good point! So better use regExp as for instance `import re` and then `re.sub(r'\s', '', stringWithWhiteSpaces)`

Answer (score 2):

What you should note is that [`lstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.lstrip) returns a copy of the string rather than modify the object. To actually update your dictionary, you'll need to assign the stripped value back to the item.

For example:

```
for k, v in your_dict.iteritems():
    your_dict[k] = v.lstrip()
```

Note the use of `.iteritems()` which returns an iterator instead of a list of key value pairs. This makes it somewhat more efficient.

I should add that [in Python3, `.item()` has been changed to return "views"](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists) and so `.iteritems()` would not be required.

Comment: Am I wrong or does strip only remove leading and trailing characters?

Comment: @ezdazuzena That it does. I'm merely sticking to the OP's example and assuming that's what he's trying to achieve. The key message here is that the stripped/replaced string has to be assigned back.

Comment: .. anyway, you're right. Though I like more the comprehension solution by monkut ;)

Answer (score 2):

I use the following. You can pass any object as an argument, including a string, list or dictionary.

```
# strip any type of object
def strip_all(x):
  if isinstance(x, str): # if using python2 replace str with basestring to include unicode type
    x = x.strip()
  elif isinstance(x, list):
    x = [strip_all(v) for v in x]
  elif isinstance(x, dict):
    for k, v in x.iteritems():
      x.pop(k)  # also strip keys
      x[ strip_all(k) ] = strip_all(v)
  return x
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you would like to strip the values of `yourDict` creating a new `dict` called `newDict`:

```
newDict = dict(zip(yourDict.keys(), [v.strip() if isinstance(v,str) else v for v in yourDict.values()]))
```

This code can handle multi-type values, so will avoid stripping `int`, `float`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Although @zquare had the best answer for this question, I feel I need to chime in with a Pythonic method that will also account for dictionary values that are not strings.  This is not recursive mind you, as it only works with one dimensional dictionary objects.

```
d.update({k: v.lstrip() for k, v in d.items() if isinstance(v, str) and v.startswith(' ')})
```

This updates the original dictionary value if the value is a string and starts with a space.

UPDATE:
If you want to use Regular Expressions and avoid using starts with and endswith.  You can use this:

```
import re
rex = re.compile(r'^\s|\s$')
d.update({k: v.strip() for k, v in d.items() if isinstance(v, str) and rex.search(v)})
```

This version strips if the value has a leading or trailing white space character.