# Stripping Newline Characters From Dicts Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, strip

How would I remove a `\n` or newline character from a dict value in Python?

```
testDict = {'salutations': 'hello', 'farewell': 'goodbye\n'}
testDict.strip('\n') # I know this part is incorrect :)
print(testDict)
```

Comment: Why didn't you strip it *before* you put it in the dictionary? Also that's a value not a key.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907788/iterating-over-a-dictionary-in-python-and-stripping-white-space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To update the dictionary in-place, just iterate over it and apply  `str.rstrip()` to values:

```
for key, value in testDict.items():
    testDict[key] = value.rstrip()
```

To create a new dictionary, you can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
testDict = {key: value.rstrip() for key, value in testDict.items()}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use dictionary comprehension:

```
testDict = {key: value.strip('\n') for key, value in testDict.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to strip a newline from the Dictionary Object. 
What you want is to iterate over all Dictionary keys and update their values.

```
for key in testDict.keys():
    testDict[key] = testDict[key].strip()
```

That would do the trick.