# Remove whitespace from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, whitespace

I'm trying to remove whitespace from a list of dictionaries in Python 3.5.

I have this:

```
lst_of_dicts = [{'code': 'AB DE', 'score': 30},
                {'code': 'DE FG', 'score': 40}]
```

And want this:

```
lst_of_dicts = [{'code': 'ABDE', 'score': 30},
                {'code': 'DEFG', 'score': 40}]
```

Other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907788/iterating-over-a-dictionary-in-python-and-stripping-white-space) have suggested `.strip()` using a dict comprehension, such as this:

```
clean_d = { k:v.strip() for k, v in d.iteritems()}
```

But I haven't been able to get it to work for my data structure as I'm a python newbie I'm afraid.

Comment: You may have problems with 'score' because it's type `int`, and `int` didn't have .strip()

Comment: for k,v in item.items():
   item[k] = v.replace(' ', '') try this

Comment: [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) returns a copy of the string with the *leading and trailing characters* removed. You are looking for [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't sweat it. Just use a `for` loop:

```
In [693]: for d in lst_of_dicts:
     ...:     d['code'].replace(' ', '')
     ...:     

In [695]: lst_of_dicts
Out[695]: [{'code': 'ABDE', 'score': 30}, {'code': 'DEFG', 'score': 40}]
```

This solution is pretty specific to your data. For a general solution that works for all string items in sub dictionaries, you might consider iterating over the keys inside a nested loop:

```
for d in lst_of_dicts:
    for k in d:
        if isinstance(d[k], str):
            d[k].replace(' ', '')
```

Comment: +1 for `replace`, though it should be noted that this will _only_ change the values corresponding to a `'code'` key (which is correct for OP's example, but not a general solution).

Comment: @ThirstforKnowledge Glad to see you have a healthy Thirst for Knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will do what you want. but strip can't remove space inside string.

```
def strip_string(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        value = value.strip()
    return value

clean_d = { k: strip_string(v) for k, v in d.iteritems() }
```

so change strip_string() like this

```
def strip_string(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        value = value.replace(' ', '') # this will remove space
    return value
```