# Remove white space in value of python dictionary without converting to string?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary and I need to remove one whitespace at the beginning of the result value.

```
dct = {   
    'data': '',
    'order': 100,
    'result': ' home page',
    'step': 'click'
}
```

So it will end up looking like this:

```
dct = {   
    'data': '',
    'order': 100,
    'result': 'home page',
    'step': 'click'
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over a dictionary in python and stripping white space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8907788/6045800)

Answer (score 0):

Just `.strip()` the values if they are strings. Here is the dictionary comprehension approach:

```py
dct = {
    'data': '',
    'order': 100,
    'result': ' home page',
    'step': 'click'
}

dct = {k: v.strip() if isinstance(v, str) else v for k, v in dct.items()}
print(dct)
```

output:

```
{'data': '', 'order': 100, 'result': 'home page', 'step': 'click'}
```

`.strip()` will remove whitespaces from both left and right side of the string. If you need it to remove the left whitespaces only, you can use `.lstrip()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the following

```
for key in dct:
    if type(dct[key]) == str:
        dct[key] = dct[key].strip()
```