# Remove whitespace from python created json file

Tags: json, python-3.x

The Python script generates a JSON file (data.json). Im trying to remove the whitespace from the JSON values, but not sure how to do this. I have tried looking into specifying seperators flag in the json.dump function. https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump. But with no luck.

Any hint/ideas?

```
import csv 
import json 

def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    jsonArray = []
      
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvf: 
        #load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 

        #convert each csv row into python dict
        for row in csvReader: 
            #add this python dict to json array
            jsonArray.append(row)
  
    #convert python jsonArray to JSON String and write to file
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)
          
csvFilePath = r'input.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'data.json'
csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

data.json

```
{
        "Primary_Permission_All": "True      ",
        "Primary_FirstName": "Donald",
        "Primary_LastName": "Duck",
        "Primary_Email": "donald@duck.com",
        "Primary_MobilePhone": "11223344                                          ",
        "Primary_Permission_Letter": "True      ",
        "Primary_Permission_Newsletter": "True      ",
        "Primary_Permission_Phone": "True      ",
        "Primary_Permission_SMS": "True      ",
        "Primary_WorkPhone": "11223344                                          "
},
```

Comment: You have to strip the whitespace from the values before passing them to `json.dumps`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over a dictionary in python and stripping white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907788/iterating-over-a-dictionary-in-python-and-stripping-white-space)